# C++ // Trying to rewrite a working code to include my function

Tags: c++, function, int, ascii, iostream

My code is supposed to print an "a" amount of numbers (1 < a < n < 100000) which are simultaneously divisible by "x" and indivisible by "y" - all this for "t" amount of data sets.

I've written a code which does just that using only the `main()` function, but - as I'm learning about functions - I'm trying to rewrite this code to include my own function. For example, if I enter t=1, n=35, x=5 and y = 14, the output should be: "5 10 15 20 25 30".

Code 1 is the code which works fine, only with the main function. Code 2 is the code I'm currently working on which is supposed to include my function "check"

I've managed to rewrite the code 2 to a point where it returns the ASCII symbols corresponding to the numbers I'm supposed to obtain, but I'm having problems converting these symbols into numbers fulfilling my requirements.
When entering "1 7 2 4" as input data, the code returns two symbols instead of "2 6".

Any help with fixing this issue would be very appreciated...

Code 1:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, n, x, y;
    cin >> t;

    for (int i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        cin >> n >> x >> y;

        for (int a=0; a<n; a++)
        {
            if ((a%x==0)&&(a%y>0))
                cout << a << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code 2:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string check (int n, int x, int y)
{
    string result;
    for (int a=0; a<n; a++)
    {
        if ((a%x==0)&&(a%y>0))
        {
            result += a;
            result += " ";
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int t, n, x, y;
    cin >> t;

    for (int i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        cin >> n >> x >> y;
        cout << check (n, x, y) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `result += a;` and `cout << a << " ";` don't do the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's the problem ?

This is because the following statement is understood by the compiler as if you wanted to add a single char to the string (so the char corresponding to the ascii code of a, if the string encoding is ascii):

```
result += a;
```

You may test this behavior of [`operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) by trying:

```
result += 64;   // ascii code for @
```

#### How to solve it ?

To get the result you expect, you need to convert `a` explicitly into a string.  So change the line to:

```
result += to_string(a);
```

#### Isn't there an easier way ?

Alternatively, if you have a lot of formatting, and if you're comfortable with streams,  you may want to consider [`stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
string check (int n, int x, int y)
{
    stringstream result;
    for (int a=0; a<n; a++)
    {
        if ((a%x==0)&&(a%y>0))
        {
            result << a << " ";
        }
    }
    return result.str();
}
```

The stringstreams behave as ordinary streams (e.g. `cout`), except that they write the result into memory.  You can then easily transform the end result using the `str()` member function.

Comment: I've actually tried this solution and kept having an error pop up: " 'to_string' was not declared in this scope", but this code does indeed run just fine on ideone... I'm running Code::Blocks 17.12 on Wind 10. Anyway, thank you! I'll look for a reason for the error.

Comment: @Aurigo To have it work with all compilers, you need to `#include <string>`.  With gcc and ideone this header seems to be included automatically when you use iostream but you can't take this for granted on all compilers.  In addition, check if Code::Block uses c++11 or later by default, or if you need to explicitly specify `-std=c++11`  (or later)

Comment: you're right, I indeed needed to specify using c++11 in Code::Blocks settings. After I did this, the code compiled smoothly in C::B. Thanks again!